Undefined reference Intel IPP with CMake
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Set IPP root directory
set(IPP_ROOT_DIR "/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11")

# Specify the directory containing the FindIPP.cmake file
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(aws-lambda-ipp LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(aws-lambda-runtime)
find_package(AWSSDK COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
find_package(IPP COMPONENTS ippi ipps ippcore REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC AWS::aws-lambda-runtime ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})
if(IPP_FOUND)
  include_directories(${IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${IPP_LIBRARIES})
endif()

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    "-Wall"
    "-Wextra"
    "-Wconversion"
    "-Wshadow"
    "-Wno-sign-conversion")

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "cxx_std_11")

aws_lambda_package_target(${PROJECT_NAME})


FindIPP.cmake
# FindIPP.cmake
#
# This module defines
#  IPP_FOUND - Set to true if IPP is found
#  IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS - Where to find IPP headers
#  IPP_LIBRARIES - The IPP libraries to link against
#  IPP_VERSION - The version of IPP found
#
# Variables that can be set before calling find_package():
#  IPP_ROOT_DIR - The root directory of the IPP installation

find_path(IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS
  NAMES ipp.h
  PATHS
    ${IPP_ROOT_DIR}/include
    $ENV{IPP_ROOT_DIR}/include
)

find_library(IPP_LIBRARY
  NAMES ippi ipps ippcore
  PATHS
    ${IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib
    ${IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib/intel64
    $ENV{IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib
    $ENV{IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib/intel64
)

if(IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS AND IPP_LIBRARY)
  set(IPP_FOUND TRUE)
  set(IPP_LIBRARIES ${IPP_LIBRARY})
  
  # Try to find the version of IPP
  file(READ "${IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}/ipp/ippversion.h" IPP_VERSION_HEADER)
  string(REGEX MATCH "#define IPP_VERSION_MAJOR[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _ ${IPP_VERSION_HEADER})
  set(IPP_VERSION_MAJOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  string(REGEX MATCH "#define IPP_VERSION_MINOR[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _ ${IPP_VERSION_HEADER})
  set(IPP_VERSION_MINOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  string(REGEX MATCH "#define IPP_VERSION_UPDATE[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _ ${IPP_VERSION_HEADER})
  set(IPP_VERSION_UPDATE ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  set(IPP_VERSION "${IPP_VERSION_MAJOR}.${IPP_VERSION_MINOR}.${IPP_VERSION_UPDATE}")

  message(STATUS "Found IPP: ${IPP_VERSION} (found suitable version ${IPP_VERSION})")
else()
  set(IPP_FOUND FALSE)
  message(STATUS "IPP not found")
endif()

mark_as_advanced(IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS IPP_LIBRARIES)

cmake
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.81.0")  
-- Found AWS SDK for C++, Version: 1.11.336, Install Root:/usr/local, Platform Prefix:, Platform Dependent Libraries: pthread;crypto;ssl;z;curl
-- Components specified for AWSSDK: core, application will be depending on libs: aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found crypto: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a  
-- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
-- LibCrypto Static Lib:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "3.0.2")  
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- Found aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Found IPP: 2021.11.0 (found suitable version 2021.11.0)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...

make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/main.cpp.o
main.cpp: In function ‘aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_response handle_request(const aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_request&)’:
main.cpp:9:69: warning: unused parameter ‘req’ [-Wunused-parameter]
    9 | static invocation_response handle_request(invocation_request const& req)
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable aws-lambda-ipp
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `handle_request(aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_request const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `ippGetLibVersion'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x34): undefined reference to `ippInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/build.make:117: aws-lambda-ipp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

What is still missing ? Any suggestions ?
Sincerely
Gianluca
I want to use IntelIPP inside AWS Lambda but after setting up CMake for Intel IPP it still do not find the function reference in the main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Set IPP root directory
set(IPP_ROOT_DIR "/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.11")

# Specify the directory containing the FindIPP.cmake file
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(aws-lambda-ipp LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(aws-lambda-runtime)
find_package(AWSSDK COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
find_package(IPP COMPONENTS ippi ipps ippcore REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC AWS::aws-lambda-runtime ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})
if(IPP_FOUND)
  include_directories(${IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${IPP_LIBRARIES})
endif()

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    "-Wall"
    "-Wextra"
    "-Wconversion"
    "-Wshadow"
    "-Wno-sign-conversion")

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "cxx_std_11")

aws_lambda_package_target(${PROJECT_NAME})


FindIPP.cmake
find_path(IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS
  NAMES ipp.h
  PATHS
    ${IPP_ROOT_DIR}/include
    $ENV{IPP_ROOT_DIR}/include
)

find_library(IPP_LIBRARY
  NAMES ippi ipps ippcore
  PATHS
    ${IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib
    ${IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib/intel64
    $ENV{IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib
    $ENV{IPP_ROOT_DIR}/lib/intel64
)

if(IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS AND IPP_LIBRARY)
  set(IPP_FOUND TRUE)
  set(IPP_LIBRARIES ${IPP_LIBRARY})
  
  # Try to find the version of IPP
  file(READ "${IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}/ipp/ippversion.h" IPP_VERSION_HEADER)
  string(REGEX MATCH "#define IPP_VERSION_MAJOR[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _ ${IPP_VERSION_HEADER})
  set(IPP_VERSION_MAJOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  string(REGEX MATCH "#define IPP_VERSION_MINOR[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _ ${IPP_VERSION_HEADER})
  set(IPP_VERSION_MINOR ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  string(REGEX MATCH "#define IPP_VERSION_UPDATE[ \t]+([0-9]+)" _ ${IPP_VERSION_HEADER})
  set(IPP_VERSION_UPDATE ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  set(IPP_VERSION "${IPP_VERSION_MAJOR}.${IPP_VERSION_MINOR}.${IPP_VERSION_UPDATE}")

  message(STATUS "Found IPP: ${IPP_VERSION} (found suitable version ${IPP_VERSION})")
else()
  set(IPP_FOUND FALSE)
  message(STATUS "IPP not found")
endif()

mark_as_advanced(IPP_INCLUDE_DIRS IPP_LIBRARIES)

cmake
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.81.0")  
-- Found AWS SDK for C++, Version: 1.11.336, Install Root:/usr/local, Platform Prefix:, Platform Dependent Libraries: pthread;crypto;ssl;z;curl
-- Components specified for AWSSDK: core, application will be depending on libs: aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found crypto: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a  
-- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
-- LibCrypto Static Lib:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "3.0.2")  
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- S2N found target: AWS::crypto
-- crypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- Found aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Found IPP: 2021.11.0 (found suitable version 2021.11.0)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ...

make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/main.cpp.o
main.cpp: In function ‘aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_response handle_request(const aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_request&)’:
main.cpp:9:69: warning: unused parameter ‘req’ [-Wunused-parameter]
    9 | static invocation_response handle_request(invocation_request const& req)
      |                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable aws-lambda-ipp
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `handle_request(aws::lambda_runtime::invocation_request const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `ippGetLibVersion'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x34): undefined reference to `ippInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/build.make:117: aws-lambda-ipp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/aws-lambda-ipp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

What is still missing ? Any suggestions ?
Sincerely
Gianluca

If by using find_library with NAMES ippi ipps ippcore you want to obtain list of 3 libraries, then you are wrong: find_library returns a single library.

@Tsyvarev So the solution is to define find_library multiple times for each different library ?

Yes, you need to call find_library several times, one time for every library.
